# Change abrupt with ng-show in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have something like this in my template:

```
<span data-ng-show="!products.specialCurrency">
    <span class="table-course-price">Something here 1</span>
</span>
<span data-ng-show="products.specialCurrency">
    <span class="table-course-price">Something here 2</span>
</span>
```

So, these spans depends on the `specialCurrency` variable. When the spans are changed between them, the change is a little bit abrupt, and I would like a change more soft, but no using animation and nothing like that.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "abrupt"? Are you experiencing an intermediate state where both or neither of the spans are shown? Or do you want to minimize the CSS reflow? How do you define "soft", if it is not about animated transitions?

Comment: instead products.specialCurrency you may define a variable like $scope.specialCurrency = products.specialCurrency; and then use specialCurrency directly. I had same issue when I was executing a condition based on object.something. Try it defining in ur controller and then invoke,would be fast I think

Comment: There is a delay while getting value from object.something versus $something

Comment: Thanks @FelisCatus and @Nishith. The solution was use `data-ng-if` instead of `data-ng-show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `data-ng-if` instead of `data-ng-show`. See if that works out for you.